# a bit confused obout listening to changes on a model in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm thinking of moving a jQuery app to backbone. I have a View which I pass a collection that creates a list of Views which are each passed models. This view outputs the information into an input. Is there a way, I can propogate automatically from the view to the associated models or is this done for me autamtically.

Say for example I have a view that looks like this:

[image]

I have the following and when I update this.update_value gets called. But how would I know which model has changed? Can I get a reference to the specific model causing the `change` event? Sorry if this sounds basic.

```
  var HomepagePositionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className:'row',
    initialize:function(){
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.update_value);
    },
    render:function(){
         var html="<div class='span2'>" + this.model.get('name') + "</div><div class='span1'><input type=text class='hp_score input-mini pull-right' value='" + this.model.get('hp_score') + "' /></div>";
         $(this.el).html(html);
         this.$('.hp_score').bind('change', this.update_model);
         return this;
    },
    update_model:function(){

      console.log('this model changed' + this.model.id); // this.model.id is not working
    }
  });
```

and

```
  var HomepagePositionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
      render:function(){
        // iterate through collection and for each model create a HomepagePositionView
      }
```

and I want the update button to be a blank if the underlying models have not changed. Is there a way in Backbone to tell which models have changed if I Church and State goes from 90 -> 95?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update_model method is being called with the wrong scope.  Within that method, "this" should refer to the HomepagePositionView but in your case it's probably referring to the DOM element that triggered the event.  A Backbone View will automatically bind methods to events with the right scope if you define an "events" object on your view.  See http://backbonejs.org/#View for more information.
For example, in HomepagePositionView remove the following line:

```
this.$('.hp_score').bind('change', this.update_model);
```

And add the following immediately after your className variable:

```
  events: {
    "change .hp_score": "update_model"
  }
```

Backbone.View will automatically bind the "update_model" method to change events on DOM elements with the hp_score class.  The "update_model" method will be called with the right scope so "this" will reference the HomepagePositionView.

Alternatively you could bind the event yourself like you're trying to do now, but do it in the initialize() method rather then the render() method since render() may be called multiple times per view.  In order to make sure that the "update_model" method is called with the right scope, you can use underscores "bind" method to create a new method which is bound to the current scope.  Something like this (but again this is unnecessary if you define an "events" object as described above):

```
var method = _.bind(this.update_model,this);
this.$('.hp_score').bind('change', method);
```

As for your second question, if there is anyway to tell if a model has changed, the only way for you to do this is to listen to "change" events on the underlying model yourself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, it seems as simple as just using the `events` hash to properly scope the method. [Here's a crude jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJDLc/) that illustrates that approach working.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, like you said, you want the view that's got the collection in it (HomepagePositionsView) to deal with the change.

I'm not sure there's an [existing backbone event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) (something like listening for a model in a collection to change) for that view to listen to in one step though, so in my opinion the neatest way to do this would be to use the pub-sub pattern.

In HomepagePositionView:

```
update_value: function() {
    Backbone.trigger('model changed', this.model); //sends off a custom event,  attaching the changed model with it
}
```

Then, in HomepagePositionsView when initialising:

```
initialize: function() {
    Backbone.on('model changed', this.dealwithChange, this); //binds this function to the event
}
```

...

```
dealWithChange: function(changedModel) {
    //you can apply your logic to the changed model here.
}
```

(And make sure you call `Backbone.off('model changed', this.dealwithChange, this);` when you are destroying HomepagePositionsView as well)